# Hibernate: Persist collection of elements by providing the ids only and return the complete instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm using Hibernate with Spring Data Repositories to persist an entity that has a collection of elements. Those elements have been previously persisted.

The entity mappings are the following:

```
@Entity
@Table
@SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq", sequenceName = "person_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "person_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="person_colors",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    private Set<Color> colors; // List of favorite colors.
    // getters, setters...                                                                   
}


@Entity
@Table
@SequenceGenerator(name = "color_seq", sequenceName = "color_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Color {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "color_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Color(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getters, setters...
```

Since colors are already persisted in the database, I'd like to persist my Person entity with only the id's of the colors (color.name could be set to anything and must be ignored). The business method would look somewhat like this:

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository; //Spring Data Repository

public void saveExample() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Color red = new Color (1, null);
    Color green = new Color (2, null);
    Color blue = new Color (3, null);

    person.setColors(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(red, green, blue)));
    save(person);
}

@Transactional
public Person save(Person person) {
    return personRepository.save(person);
}
```

We want to send only the color ids for simplicity but get the persistence context to provide the complete entities for the colors so that the return value of my save() function holds the correct names of the colors, even when null was sent.

Comment: so the colors are already in the DB and you want give person only the three id`s of the persisted colors right? Does Person has already a connection to colors at the state of save?

Comment: Exactly! A connection at what level? It has the relational mappings in hibernate and the referential integrity in the DB as well.

Comment: But the person is not in db at this moment? just the colors?

Comment: Correct. Just the colors. The person is completely new.

Comment: I think you have to fetch the Colors from the DB first instead of creating new ones. After that you can give these colors to a new person. If you want only the Id you need maybe a new contructor in person entity. What do your think?